# Bot Framework mixed user input images/text

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, botframework, chatbot

I'm currently trying to make a chatbot where at a certain point the user needs to upload some images and after that can add some notes to the images. Now i wonder if it's possible to build the bot at such a way that the user can send images and text mixed and click a button "done uploading" when he isn't going to send more images/text? If this is possible i would like to know how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which channel are running your bot in? In most channels, uploading a photo or attachment is a function of the channel, not the bot. The bot merely acts on the photo/attachment having been sent. Are you wanting to prompt the user to send a photo as a function of the bot and NOT use any built in features of the channel?

Comment: I want to prompt the user for both pictures and text at the same time, and use the same validator for both

Comment: Which channel...web chat, Facebook, something else?